# Lightroom Classic 9.4: enabled "store presets with my catalog" but when I imported an .xmp preset, it was NOT inside my catalog

Tags: lightroom

as above.

I did a search on my catalog folder (on a mac so I used the find command/terminal) and no xmp file there. But I can see the imported preset inside a folder called "ImportedSomethingSomething" which is located inside an Adobe folder (in my case it's inside /User/myuser/Library/Application Support/Adobe).

Am I doing something wrong? How can I make Lightroom behave like what the setting says it should do which is "store presets with my catalog".

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*Store with* does not mean *store inside*; what it means is to store them w/in the folder structure where the catalogue resides. It also does not move/copy the user presets that already exist, it only stores new ones there; if you want currently existing user presets to be copied there, then you have to move them manually.

It does copy default LR presets to w/in the folder structure for every catalogue; which is a lot of duplication if you have numerous catalogues... About the only time this option should be used is if you have a complete catalogue (.cat/.dat/image files) on an external drive that you want to work with on multiple computers (w/o syncing).